# Store LINQ context as Request variable or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, request

Is this a nice way to use the LINQ context during one http request? In almost every request i have some selects from the database and some inserts/updates. It seams to work but I dont know how this will work with heavy traffic to the servers and on load balanced servers, anyone have any opinions/ideas about this way to keep the Context during the entire lifespan of the Request?

```
public static AccountingDataContext Accounting
{
    get
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("AccountingDataContext"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("AccountingDataContext", new AccountingDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer.Accounting"].ConnectionString));
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Items["AccountingDataContext"] as AccountingDataContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a generally good idea on some levels. But you probably want to push instantiation back from the Begin_Request event. With the integrated pipeline, you will be initializing a rather expensive DB Context for every single request to your site. Including favicon.ico, all your stylesheets and all your images.

Best, simple implementation of something that only instantiates it when something asks for the context is [Ayende's example for NHibernate's ISession](http://ayende.com/blog/4805/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-limiting-session-scope); you can just replace it with the appropriate bits to instantiate your L2S context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Unity for dependency injection, but the idea is the same:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
    var childContainer = this.Container.CreateChildContainer();
    HttpContext.Current.Items["container"] = childContainer;
    this.ControllerFactory.RegisterTypes(childContainer);
}

protected void Application_EndRequest() {
    var container = HttpContext.Current.Items["container"] as IUnityContainer;

    if (container != null) {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The container is responsible for setting up a number of things, one of which is the data context. Works like a charm. I haven't done load balancing, but can't imagine you'd run into issues there either. The request gets its own context, which is wrapping a single user connecting to a database. No different that using old school ADO .NET for data access.